# error: ‘LIBNET_ERR_FATAL’ with libnet

Tags: c, linux, libnet

I write a demo with libnet, but get an error when call the function:

```
libnet_error(LIBNET_ERR_FATAL, "libnet_open_link_interface: %s\n", errbuf);
```

The error is "error: ‘LIBNET_ERR_FATAL’ undeclared (first use in this function)".

my gcc command is: "gcc demo.c `libnet-config --defines --cflags --libs`", and run on ubuntu.

I want to know who got the same error before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the version problem,  LIBNET_ERR_FATAL have been removed in 1.1!

Comment: Which version contains `LIBNET_ERR_FATAL`?

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answer, the `LIBNET_ERR_FATAL` and the function `libnet_error()` and some other good old things are included in `libnet-1.0.2a`. You can still download a compilable source here: https://code.google.com/p/ips-builder/downloads/detail?name=libnet-1.0.2a.tar.gz&can=2&q=

As I tried, it can be compiled on `Ubuntu 12.04` with `gcc 4.6.3`. Do remember to add `sudo` before running the `make install`. Otherwise, it will fail to create the `user/include/libnet` due to permission issue.